# Moment.js toDate does not always return a Date instance

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Basically, I need to calculate the expiration date for a (very long-living) cookie, so I want to do *now + 99 years*. As this is way easier when using a library such as Moment.js than with native JavaScript, I am doing:

```
var expirationDate = moment().add('years', 99);
```

But I need a JavaScript `Date` object and call the `toUTCString` function on it to get the properly formatted string for the cookie. Hence I am doing:

```
var expirationDate = m().add('years', 99).toDate().toUTCString();
```

Now, something very strange happens. When I run this line in a Node.js shell, everything is fine. But if I run it from within a script, it fails. The error message is

> TypeError: Object Mon, 24 Oct 2112 07:34:34 GMT has no method 'toUTCString'

which is correct as the *thing* returned by `toDate` is no instance of `Date`, but just a plain old object. Curiously enough, when I try the exact same thing in the Node.js REPL, `toDate` returns an instance of `Date`.

I run both, the REPL and the script, using Node.js 0.8.25, both on the same machine. Moment.js is version 2.3.1.

Any idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: Just to be sure, is `m` an alias to `moment` in your code ? Or are the parenthesis an error ?

Comment: You're so right! `m` was just an alias for `moment`, but the error came from the following line, where I handed over the created object to a function, which tried to call `toUTCString` internally. Hence it failed. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction :-)!

Comment: since you already use momentjs, why didn't you just use moment to print out the utc string?   `moment().add('years', 99).utc().format();`

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to do this in one step:

```
moment().add('years', 99).toISOString()
```

But I think the main problem was identified by dystroy in comments.

Answer (score -1):

did you try something like:

`expirationDate = new Date(moment().add('years', 99));` ?

This way, You will get back a date insteance, I tried MomentJs's .toDate() but it did not suite my needs.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.